# Why useQuery refetch() doesn't work sometimes?

Tags: react-native, graphql

I use `react-native` with `graphql`.

I have a query and tried to use `refetch`.

```
  const { data: updatePhoto, refetch } = useQuery(SEE_PHOTO_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      id: photoId,
    },
  });
```

when after I edit my comment, I want to `refetch` this query and put it on `setState` in order to change UI.

```
  const onEditValid = async ({ comments }) => {
    const commentId = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@commentId");
    await editCommentMutation({
      variables: {
        id: parseInt(commentId),
        payload: comments,
      },
      update: updateEditComment,
    });
  };

  const updateEditComment = async (cache, result) => {
    const {
      data: {
        editComment: { error, ok, id },
      },
    } = result;
    if (ok) {
      const commentId = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@commentId");
      const { comments } = getValues();
      await textRef.current.clear();
      await refetch();
      setState(updatePhoto);
      await cache.modify({
        id: `Comment:${commentId}`,
        fields: {
          payload(prev) {
            return comments;
          },
        },
      });
    }
  };
```

But UI doesn't change.
I tried to change UI by `modifying cache` and `refetching data`. But both fails for a week.. :(

I also raised the question about fail of `cache modify`
=> [React Native: `cache.modity` doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71223286/react-native-cache-modity-doesnt-work)

But no one answers.

I really need your help.. please help me

Comment: where is editCommentMutation function?

Comment: and where use refetch function ?